# Find how much column one has occurences of column two

Tags: bash

This is my file:

```
col1 col2
Me apple
You banana
Me banana
Me apple
You banana
Me coconut 
He coconut
Me coconut
```

The expected result:

```
Me has 2 apple
You has 2 banana
Me has 1 banana
Me has 2 coconut
He has 1 coconut
```

It should count every thing to see who has how how much of what fruit.

I googled some `sort` and uniq` commands but the expected result wasn't seen.

The names of both column 1 and column 2 are not static, they're dynamic.

Comment: use an associative array whose keys are the two columns. You increment the value whenever you get a repeat.

Comment: @Barmar can you hint me more and the name of commands?

Comment: `((counters[$line]++))` will increment the counter for the line.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I got it, yes, I want all results not only one or two. I just wrote a sample (but maybe lack of everything in sample). I mean all fruits should be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A array
while read -r col1 col2; do
  ((array["$col1" "$col2"]++))
done < <(tail -n+2 file.txt)

for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "${i/ /" has ${array[$i]} "}"
done
```

---

- This assumes that `col1` does not have a space/tabs in it. e.g. col1 =  `"I am"` , and col2 is `apple`

Comment: Thanks, in fact the fruit names are two columns, the second and the third one (or maybe from two to four). I see some misbehaving acts during the counts. Can you modify that or help me?

Comment: Your question is pretty clear, two columns  only, nothing in there says it has spaces.

Comment: Yes sir, you're right. May I edit the question with more columns after first?